# Google Chrome shows HTTP server response as plain text instead of rendering some webpage

Tags: google-chrome, rendering

I surfed to Alexa.com (the internet ranking company) and wanted to see at which position my personal site is ranked. But look what I've got in my Chrome browser:

[image]

---

Chrome is not rendering the HTTP response. It simply shows the entire stream. It also does so for windowslive.com. I tested it with many other sites and it's OK. I also tested it for the same sites many times and it doesn't render anything.

The version of my Chrome browser is 14.0.835.124.

Does anyone know what is wrong with Chrome? Where the problem is?

Comment: Working perfectly fine on `Linux x86_64 15.0.865.0 dev`.

Comment: Works for me.  Check the headers though, `HTP/1.1 200 OK` and `r: httpd`.  Are you behind some proxy contraption?

Comment: @fvu, how should I know that I'm behind a proxy? I'm not good at networking.

Comment: @saeed just wondering who/what/where mutilated those headers...

Comment: I have the same issue as well :(

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/487370/google-chrome-shows-garbage-text-instead-of-web-page