# Google Chrome shows garbage text instead of web page

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

On some websites, I receive garbage text instead of web page itself. I have noticed that this only happens for pages that are served with **Content-Encoding** set to **GZIP** or **chunked** headers, see the image please:

[image]

I am using latest version 22.0.1229.94 of Chrome with Windows 7 Ultimaate. The encoding of browser is set to UTF-8. (I also tried changing encoding to Western, etc but same result)

Can anyone suggest a solution to this? Thanks

Comment: Maybe your ISP's proxy? Can you see those websites properly on IE or Firefox?

Comment: @jaume: Yes working fine in other browsers IE, FF, Opera

Comment: Can you share the URL of the website so that we can test better - look at the headers, etc?

Comment: One of the sites it happens is at sourgeforge.net. Actually on the page where download initiates automatically.